# Dependent and independent events: Students

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability, independence

> [image]

I am trying to answer this one from Khan Academy.

My only question is about the first question.

1. For the first question the answer is 120/300.
   My question about this is that 120 is just the students with at least one sister. The question was how many students have a sister, not at least one sister. Is not the right answer should be (120+40)/300 since 40 the students also has at least a sister (and a brother)? Or are the 40 students already included in 120 students?

If it is, to me it does not seem automatic that 40 is already included in 120.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 40 is included because those students have at least one sister; naturally, they're in the set of students that has at least one sister (i.e. 120 students). This means, there are 80 students with at least one sister and no brothers.

Answer (score 0):

You argued with

> ... The question was how many students have a sister, not at least one sister.

The term “at least one” means “1 or more”, so:

- If someone **has** a sister, it has indeed **at least one** sister.
- Reversely, if someone has **at least one** sister, he indeed **has** a sister.

So these two statements are equivalent, and the result 120/300 is correct.